# Make a phrase column out of columns with value of 1 in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this dataset, I want to create a phrase column that adds a word for each column with value of 1...

```
    SINNOUVEAU  PERTETOTAL  CHANGGARAN  SOCLOCATIO  SINISAMEDI  NOMASCONDU  SINIREPET
0            1           0           0           0           0           1          0
1            0           1           0           0           0           1          0
2            0           0           1           0           0           1          0
```

This is the dataframe for the phrase values for each column if set to 1:

```
          col                  phr
0  SINNOUVEAU     sinistre nouveau
1  PERTETOTAL         perte totale
2  CHANGGARAN  changement garantie
3  SOCLOCATIO     societe location
4  SINISAMEDI               samedi
5  NOMASCONDU        nom different
6   SINIREPET   sinistre repetitif
```

So, for the dataframe above, this is the result I expect:

```
    SINNOUVEAU  PERTETOTAL  CHANGGARAN  SOCLOCATIO  SINISAMEDI  NOMASCONDU  SINIREPET  Phrase
0            1           0           0           0           0           1          0  sinistre nouveau, nom different
1            0           1           0           0           0           1          0  perte totale, nom different
2            0           0           1           0           0           1          0  changement garantie, nom different
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the first dataset is named `df` and the second one as `df1`:
We take help of [`df.dot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) like below:

```
m=df.rename(columns=df1.set_index('col')['phr'].to_dict())
df['Phrase']=m.dot(m.columns+',').str.rstrip(',')
print(df)
```

---

```
   SINNOUVEAU  PERTETOTAL  CHANGGARAN  SOCLOCATIO  SINISAMEDI  NOMASCONDU  \
0           1           0           0           0           0           1   
1           0           1           0           0           0           1   
2           0           0           1           0           0           1   

   SINIREPET                             Phrase  
0          0     sinistre nouveau,nom different  
1          0         perte totale,nom different  
2          0  changement garantie,nom different
```

Comment: More like you solution , but with map :-)

Comment: @WenYoBen nice one :)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
s=df.dot(df.columns.map(df1.set_index('col').phr)+',').str[:-1]
s
0       sinistrenouveau,nomdifferent
1           pertetotale,nomdifferent
2    changementgarantie,nomdifferent
dtype: object
df['Phr']=s
```